# Sending data from Angular to Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I don't understand why I cannot get the data I POST form with Angular.js Express.

Angular Part :

```
$http.post(baseURL+"/search", data).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.results = data;
    });
```

Express Part :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query, req.body, req.params);
});
```

The log is {} {} {}.
I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

I also tried :

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url : baseURL+"/search",
    data : {name: 'tete'},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).success( function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

It doesn't work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular sends data as JSON by default.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post //Content-Type: application/json
```

You're only including the `urlencoded` body-parser middleware. You need to include `bodyParser.json()`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Angular `$http` service sends data as JSON and you're missing appropriate bodyParser.

Try replacing your bodyParser with `app.use(bodyParser.json());` before your POST route in Express.